# How to prepare statement for update query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

I have a mysqli query with the following code:

```
$db_usag->query("UPDATE Applicant SET phone_number ='$phone_number', 
street_name='$street_name', city='$city', county='$county', zip_code='$zip_code', day_date='$day_date', month_date='$month_date',
 year_date='$year_date' WHERE account_id='$account_id'");
```

However all the data is extracted from HTML documents so to avoid errors I would like to use a prepared statement. I found [PHP documentation on `bind_param()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) but there is no UPDATE example.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

An `UPDATE` works the same as an insert or select.  Just replace all the variables with `?`.

```
$sql = "UPDATE Applicant SET phone_number=?, street_name=?, city=?, county=?, zip_code=?, day_date=?, month_date=?, year_date=? WHERE account_id=?";

$stmt = $db_usag->prepare($sql);

// This assumes the date and account_id parameters are integers `d` and the rest are strings `s`
// So that's 5 consecutive string params and then 4 integer params

$stmt->bind_param('sssssdddd', $phone_number, $street_name, $city, $county, $zip_code, $day_date, $month_date, $year_date, $account_id);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->error) {
  echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
}
else echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: apart from the original question do you have any idea if the prepare statement has unicode support ? I need to store some arabic  names

Comment: @ArabMichael: Make your database use UTF8 encoding, set your PHP's internal encoding to UTF8 ([iconv_set_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php)) and you should be fine.

Comment: Michael answers to ArabMichael :D

Comment: @DannyG Doing some archaeology?  Way back then I used to go by plain Michael, and the OP as ArabMichael.

Comment: Kind of that, hehe, got into this question somehow, noticed the fact and commented :)

Comment: Similar issue with a prepared update statement from a jquery get. This solved my problem

Comment: And what about scalar variable, how prepared statement is used in this way (...WHERE account_id='{$account_id}'");