# Updating database entry using PHP not working for text fields

Tags: php, database, mysqli, sql-update

Im trying to run the following code but it is giving me a strange error..

```
$result = $db->query("UPDATE `items` 
          SET `item_label`= ".$title.", 
              `item_quantity`=".$quantity.", `item_price`=".$price."
          WHERE `item_id` = ".$_POST['id']);
```

If i remove the `item_label` = ".$title.", from the above code it works perfectly and successfully updates the quantity and price of the given row. e.g.

```
$result = $db->query("UPDATE `items` 
          SET `item_quantity`=".$quantity.",
              `item_price`=".$price." 
         WHERE `item_id` = ".$_POST['id']);
```

when I run the code containing the item_label section it fails to set the item_label. and it gives the following error message..

> Unknown column 'Updated Text' in 'field list'

Now the "Updated Text" is the value of $title.

Im baffled as to how / why it is viewing this content as a column header!?

any ideas as to why this would happen?

Comment: (1) If you print out the SQL after parameter substitution, the error is obvious 95% of the time.  (2) Use parameters rather than munging the strings.  (3) You probably are missing single quotes around one of the values (see (2)).

Comment: You aren't wrapping the text in any quotation marks, therefore when it executes it looks like "UPDATE items SET `item_label`=Updated Text, `item_quantity`....".  Further, the benefit of using mysqli is to take advantage of bindings to prevent SQL injection attacks.  See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6514730/870729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its a String you should give quotes around the `$title`

> I would have done something like below

```
$result = $db->query("UPDATE items SET item_label = '".$title."', item_quantity=$quantity,item_price=$price WHERE item_id =$_POST['id']");
```