# Error when trying to update a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to update my MySQL table but I keep getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INTO kh_comments (id, author, comment, 'timestamp', abstract,
>   date_of_abstract) ' at line 1

This is how I am trying to update the table *kh_comments*:

```
public function prepare($author, $arr) {
    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE INTO kh_comments (id, author, comment, timestamp, abstract, date_of_abstract) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('dssdss', '1', $author, '', 0, $value['id'], $value['date']);
        }
        else {
            echo $conn->error;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to update existing rows or insert new rows?

Comment: `UPDATE kh_comments SET col = value, col1=value ........`

Comment: Why don't you just read a simple documentation? This is not a logical error

Comment: @Philipp I would like to insert a new row, if there is no row existing with the same values that I am giving. If a row exists with the same values, it should only be updated.

Comment: Look at the manual for [INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

TIMESTAMP is a restricted keyword in MySQL.

Use backticks for your table- and fieldnames, ie

```
"UPDATE `kh_comments` (`id`, `author`, `comment`, `timestamp`, ..."
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: Timestamp is a keyword, not a reserved word. Plus, when is that even the syntax of an update stmt !

Answer (score 0):

Use this way.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE kh_comments SET id=?, author=?, comment=?, timestamp=?, abstract=?, date_of_abstract=?";
if ($stmt) {             
    $stmt->bind_param('dssdss', '1', $author, '', 0, $value['id'], $value['date']);

}
```

For more info, click [Prepare Statement For Update Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514649/php-mysql-bind-param-how-to-prepare-statement-for-update-query)

Comment: Update is in a foreach. So you only need to prepare the query ONCE and bind then execute in the loop

Comment: Ok OK @RiggsFolly. Didn't saw that. *~Thanks*

Comment: You might want to add a `->execute()` in there somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I think your update syntax is incorrect try using below function :

```
public function prepare($author, $arr) {
    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE kh_comments (id, author, comment, timestamp, abstract, date_of_abstract) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {             
            $stmt->bind_param('dssdss', '1', $author, '', 0, $value['id'], $value['date']);
        }
        else {
            echo $conn->error;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You have no `->execute()` you might want to add one of those! Also move `->prepare()` outside the loop. It only needs running once

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment

> *I would like to insert a new row, if there is no row existing with the same values that I am giving. If a row exists with the same values, it should only be updated*

You need to use the `INSERT.... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` syntax to do that

You also can prepare the statement once outside the loop and then execute it many times with new parameters.

Also as one of your column names is `timestamp` which is a MYSQL reserved word, that column needs to be wrapped in backticks, or better still renamed

```
public function prepare($author, $arr) {
    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `kh_comments` 
                   (`id`, `author`, `comment`, `timestamp`, `abstract`, `date_of_abstract`) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
            ON DUPLICATE 
              UPDATE `author` = ?, `comment`=?, `timestamp`=?, 
                     `abstract`=?, `date_of_abstract`=?
              WHERE `id` = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $stmt->bind_param('dssdssssdssd', 
                           '1', $author, '', NOW(), $value['id'], $value['date'],
                           $author, '', NOW(), $value['id'], $value['date'], '1' );
        $stmt->execute()
        if ( $stmt === false )
            echo $conn->error;
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

> Of course this code will only work once as you are using the `'1'` as the `id` in all the rows you are trying to store.

Answer (score -1):

Your UPDATE statement syntax wrong, for your reference I have tried to correct your code.

```
public function prepare($author, $arr) {
    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
    $sql="UPDATE kh_comments SET author= ?, comment = ?, timestamp= ?, abstract = ?, date_of_abstract= ? WHERE id= ?";
    foreach ($arr as $value) {    
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('1', $author, '', 0, $value['id'], $value['date'],'dssdss');
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->errno) {
          echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
        }
        else echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";
    }
}
```

Please check order of parameters which I have defined. and make change as you need

Comment: Move the prepare outside the foreach loop

Comment: Your `bind_param()` is nonsense

Comment: @RiggisFolly, can you explain how it nonsense?

Comment: Look at your `bind_param()` statement and compare it with [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Also see that OP wants to do a INSERT if no row exists and an UPDATE if a row does exist