# How to update specific table row in mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am beginner in php , i am trying to update specific row but does not work . i need your help: 
       **update.php**
      DIR . '/db_connect.php';
           // connecting to db
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

```
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

$id = $_POST["id"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
  $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE citizenalert set location={'$location'} WHERE id ={'$id'}");
}

  ?>
```

**db_config.php**

```
  <?php

   define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
   define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
     define('DB_DATABASE', "ikirenga"); // database name
      define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
     ?>
```

**db_connect.php**

```
           <?php

  class DB_CONNECT {

// constructor
function __construct() {
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // closing db connection
    $this->close();
}

/**
 * Function to connect with database
 */
function connect() {
    // import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());


    // Selecing database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

    // returing connection cursor
    return $con;
}

/**
 * Function to close db connection
 */
function close() {
    // closing db connection
    mysql_close();
}
    }
   ?>
```

**request_update.php**

```
               <!doctype html>

                <html lang="en">

                   <body>
                  <form name="updates" method="post" action="update.php" > 
                   <label>User location</label> <input id="location"  type="text" name="location" > <br><br>
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
                     </form>  
                     </body>
                     </html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: chk your connection ist, and your code is open for SQL Injection.

Comment: connection is ok . no error i am getting

Comment: `UPDATE citizenalert set location='yourVal' WHERE id = YourID` run manually in code and php myadmin., also check `print_r($_POST)` what are u getting... before `if (isset($_POST['id'])) {`

Comment: u r producing: `UPDATE citizenalert set location={'test'} WHERE id ={'1'} ` which is wrong for WHERE

Comment: It amazes me that people are still using mysql_ functions still to this day.

Comment: No wonder. 60% of stackoverflow shows it

Comment: all beginner using this... @Drew, dont know why teachers accept this.

Comment: @devpro sad thing is that they are probably commercial websites http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297105/mysql-real-escape-string-not-working-for-this-specific-example-mysql-real-escap#comment64014116_38297105

Comment: i say, if you are beginner, explore new things, @Drew

Answer (score 0):

Please use below Syntax

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

$id = $_POST["id"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
$sql = mysql_query(" UPDATE citizenalert set location = " . $location . "   WHERE id = " . $id . ");
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: who knows, `$location` is string or integer.

Comment: sql injection here

Comment: $location is a string

Comment: @NiragireSam: did u checked the others answers??

Comment: yes i am checking it and i don't find any change

Comment: @NiragireSam: this is not working? `$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE citizenalert set location='{$location}' WHERE id = '{$id}'");`

Comment: @devpro . YES is not working ,i don't know why . my table has two columns id and location . look at my form where i type value of location to update existing one . `<form name="uploadForm" method="post" action="update.php" > 
                    <label>Name</label> <input type="text" name="location" > <br><br>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  </form>`

Comment: @NiragireSam: missing ID in your form. where is ID field...

Comment: @devpro , i added it like this  **id="location"** but still not update  i get

Comment: @NiragireSam:where? please share the full code.

Comment: @devpro i share full code . check it and let me know  why . Tnx

Comment: @NiragireSam: i have checked, u dont have `$_POST['id']` u cant get it by using `id=` etc... u need a input field for ID... what u expect the value of `ID`?

Comment: just i need to know if there is not any way i can update any table row without specifying its id statically in input field or in codes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL query as below

```
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE citizenalert set location='{$location}' WHERE id = '{$id}'");
```

Comment: sql injection here

Answer (score 0):

*If i test your code something like that:*

```
<?php 
$id = 1;
$location = "test";
echo $sql="UPDATE citizenalert set location={'$location'} WHERE id ={'$id'}";
?>
```

*It's giving this query:*

```
UPDATE citizenalert set location={'test'} WHERE id ={'1'}
```

Please check here, both of values having issue.

**Problem:**

You are using `{}` outside the quotes. you need to use it inside the single quote.

**Modified Query with same example:**

```
echo $sql="UPDATE citizenalert set location='{$location}' WHERE id ='{$id}'";
```

**Result:**

```
UPDATE citizenalert set location='test' WHERE id ='1'
```

**Side Notes:**

- Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), because `mysql_*` is deprecated and closed in **PHP 7**.
- Your code is open for SQL Injection, you must need to protect with SQL Injection or just simply use [**Prepared Statement**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

*Some other Reference for Prepared Statement:*
*[php mysql bind-param, how to prepare statement for update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514649/php-mysql-bind-param-how-to-prepare-statement-for-update-query)*